# Wemos D1 reset when setting pins mode

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm building a little car, remote controlled by a Wemos D1 board, in order to set the WiFi connection and the control logic I'm running this script:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* pass = "**********";
const char* ssid = "**********";

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,91);
IPAddress gat(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress dns(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress sub(255,255,255,0);

WiFiServer s(2000);

int inA1 = 1;
int inA2 = 2;
int enA = 3;
int inB1 = 4;
int inB2 = 5;
int enB = 6;
int trigger = 7;
int echo = 8;
double vSuono = 343; //Unità di misura: m/s
int speed = 255;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.config(ip,gat,sub,dns);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
  delay(500);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(".");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected!");
  delay(30);

  s.begin();
  Serial.println("Server running!");
  delay(30);

  //Here starts the problems
  pinMode(inA1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inA2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inB1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inB2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigger,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo,INPUT);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  WiFiClient c = s.available();
  delay(30);
  if(c){
    Serial.println("New client connected!");
    delay(3);
    while(c.connected()){
      if(c.available()){
        String command = c.readStringUntil('\n');

        if(command == "forward"){
          Serial.println("forward");
          forward(speed);
        }else if(command == "right"){
          Serial.println("right");
          right(speed);
        }else if(command == "left"){
          Serial.println("left");
          left(speed);
        }else{
          Serial.println("back");
          back(speed);
        }
      }
      delay(30);
    }
    c.stop();
  }
}

void forward(int velocita){
  digitalWrite(inA1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inB2,LOW);
  analogWrite(enA,velocita);
  analogWrite(enB,velocita);
}

void left(int velocita){
  digitalWrite(inA1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB2,HIGH);
  analogWrite(enA,velocita);
  analogWrite(enB,velocita);
}

void right(int velocita){
  digitalWrite(inA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inA2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inB1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inB2,LOW);
  analogWrite(enA,velocita);
  analogWrite(enB,velocita);
}

void back(int velocita){
  digitalWrite(inA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inA2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB2,HIGH);
  analogWrite(enA,velocita);
  analogWrite(enB,velocita);
}

void stop(){
  digitalWrite(inA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(inB2,LOW);
}
```

The problem is that when the board execute the pinMode function in the setup() block, the board stop the execution, crash and restart, and I'm not able to ping the board.
If I comment all the portion of the setup() block, with the pinMode calls, the program starts to work but obviously I can't use the pins.
On the serial monitor when the board crash appears this messages:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the pin mapping by heart, but you should stick to the GPIO pins named D1, D2...D8. You've named them 1, 2...8 which are different pins. You likely used a pin which is used by something else (like serial or reset).

```
int inA1 = D1;
int inA2 = D2;
int enA = D3;
int inB1 = D4;
int inB2 = D5;
int enB = D6;
int trigger = D7;
int echo = D8;
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I implemented the control logic on an arduino uno clone, and when I name the pin 1,2,3... the script works, but on wemos d1 this don't happen. However I will change the pin name also on the arduino uno version.Thank you very much.

Comment: changing the pin  names on the Arduino Uno won't work. The names are designed for the Wemos D1 only. The defines are included automatically by the IDE when you select the target board in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same wdt reset error while trying to use pinMode with digitalWrite() function. 
I solved it by figuring out how the Wemos Pin mapping works. 
Actually, you need to refer the pin in 'Dx' notation. 
e.g
 `digitalWrite(D15,LOW);`
or

```
pinMode(D15, OUTPUT);
```

Also, make sure to select "Wemos D1 R1" in Tools > Boards so that Dx constants will match
 the labels.

Have a look at the conversation here on Arduino FOrum to understand more about wemos pin mapping:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=545113.0